# ApolloServer not firing custom directives

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to write some authentication logic based on apollo server documentation but it doesn't seem to be firing. Here's my code:

```js
// schemas/auth-schema.js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @auth(requires: Role = ADMIN) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION
`;
```

```js
// directives/auth-directive.js
import { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from 'apollo-server';

export default class AuthDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitObject(type) {
    console.log('HERE');
  }
  visitSchema() {
    console.log('HERE');
  }
  visitFieldDefinition() {
    console.log('HERE');
  }
}
```

```js
// schemas/post-schema.js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Post } from '../models';

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Post @auth(requires: ADMIN) {
    body: String!
    description: String!
    id: ID!
    image: String!
    publishedAt: DateTime
    readingTime: Int!
    slug: String!
    title: String!
  }

  input PostInput {
    body: String!
    description: String!
    image: String!
    publishedAt: DateTime
    title: String!
  }

  extend type Query {
    posts: [Post!]! @auth(requires: ADMIN)
  }

  extend type Mutation {
    addPost(input: PostInput!): Post! @auth(requires: ADMIN)
  }
`;

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    posts: () => Post.find({}),
  },
  Mutation: {
    addPost: (_, { input }) => Post.create(input),
  },
};
```

```js
// index.js

import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import AuthDirective from './directives/auth-directive';
import * as config from './config';

mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', config.env !== 'production');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  modules: [
    require('./schema/auth-schema'),
    require('./schema/date-schema'),
    require('./schema/post-schema'),
    require('./schema/role-schema'),
    require('./schema/user-schema'),
  ],
  schemaDirectives: {
    auth: AuthDirective,
  },
});

async function boot() {
  await mongoose.connect(config.mongo.url);
  await server.listen(config.http.port);
  console.log(`server listening on port ${config.http.port}`);
}

async function shutdown() {
  await server.stop();
  await mongoose.disconnect();
  console.log(`server shutted down`);
  process.exit(0);
}

process.on('SIGINT', shutdown);
process.on('SIGTERM', shutdown);

boot();
```

So, I've tried putting the @auth directive in every possible case and nothing is being fired.

```js
type Post @auth(requires: ADMIN) { ... } // not firing

type Query {
  posts: [Post!]! @auth(requires: ADMIN) // not firing
}
```

This is what AdminDirective is evaluated from the console:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At a glance, that setup looks correct. What version of apollo-server are you using?

Comment: @DanielRearden I am using apollo-server version 2.4.0

Comment: Hmm I just tested that code locally and it works fine for me.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the complete `auth-schema.js`?

Comment: Also, if you log the value for `AuthDirective` inside `index.js`, does it show as defined?

Comment: @DanielRearden edited

Comment: Can you try to use `makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers, schemaDirectives });` instead of the schema-modules.I also had problems using the `schemaDirectives` property in the ApolloServer Config object. Might be an issue with ApolloServer

Answer (score 2):

So, looking at the code for `apollo-server`, when you use the `modules` option, internally your schema is built using `buildServiceDefinition`. While this function does merge directives from all the modules, it's not passed your `schemaDirectives` object and does not apply it.

In other words, this looks like a bug with `apollo-server` itself. You can file an issue, and in the meantime, just use the `typeDefs` and `resolvers` options, combining the necessary files yourself.

Comment: Alright, it looks like if you swap modules with schema and use makeExecutableSchema works fine. It's a shame thou, it looked much cleaner the other way :'( Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: It looks like an issue has already been opened but with not much attention: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2046

Comment: @brielov You could take a look at using [merge-graphql-schemas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-graphql-schemas) in addition to `makeExecutableSchema`. That's what I'm actually using in one project.

Comment: I will definitely take a look at it. Thank you!